AsposePDF Encryption bug under .NET 9.0
When attempting to encrypt an AsposePDF.Document (version 21.12.0), the following test:
using Aspose.Pdf;
using Aspose.Pdf.Facades;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace qbo4.Document.AsposePDF.Tests
{
    public class Sample
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Proof of concept for .net9.0 bug
        /// </summary>
        [Fact]
        public async Task Encrypt()
        {
            using var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("Samples\\LoremIpsum.pdf");
            var document = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(stream, true);
            document.Encrypt("UserPwd", "OwnerPwd", DocumentPrivilege.AllowAll, CryptoAlgorithm.AESx256, false);
        }
    }
}

succeeds in .NET 8.0, but fails in .NET 9.0 with the following message:
Message: 
#=zG5rLZShdh3CELHyHFONFsmrfaE_HOBi$4cDy6i8= : Permissions check failed (invalid Perms value).

Stack Trace:    
#=zeTEHGseWl$E2b74zvJPs0HHe2GrvBVcqxoAIPjc=.#=znlBKJSgVZQ$X(Byte[] #=zoJc0bBFZx5L_, Byte[] #=z5PP7WSAN_Puf)
#=zeTEHGseWl$E2b74zvJPs0HHe2GrvBVcqxoAIPjc=.#=zbKiLPP9rrbwe(Byte[] #=z5yMKBFc=, Byte[] #=zsCj_mHU=, Byte[] #=zJRqMY5E=, Byte[] #=zax0MxxE=, Byte[] #=zhUOtHjw=, Byte[] #=zb2D18pKtXA6C)
#=zeTEHGseWl$E2b74zvJPs0HHe2GrvBVcqxoAIPjc=.#=zbKiLPP9rrbwe(String #=z5yMKBFc=)
#=zeTEHGseWl$E2b74zvJPs0HHe2GrvBVcqxoAIPjc=.#=zpNY3WNU=()
#=zN0AKskZRa4sFhJb929qOWL0wOw2ARAWaIurPKls=.#=z3T6JzbY=(#=zcyQeqqe7an_SpTkOfNvmJP1IH0O2I6qiCW3EGhc= #=zfa0GOts=)
#=zCBpuUhOf9gLm4eLHWOipVbPjidD4p1BOQ_PAXYg=.ctor(#=zTFxHU34pwOp5ybVTSXLvyvVL$UUeaQ6YBTADGfoxdNCl #=zufuHgWxtWLBjto91QQ==, Byte[] #=zhwE5S8o=, Int32 #=zyvQDV$M=, String #=z5yMKBFc=)
#=zCBpuUhOf9gLm4eLHWOipVbPjidD4p1BOQ_PAXYg=.#=z2Uv03sc=(#=zTFxHU34pwOp5ybVTSXLvyvVL$UUeaQ6YBTADGfoxdNCl #=zufuHgWxtWLBjto91QQ==, Byte[] #=zhwE5S8o=, String #=z5yMKBFc=)
#=zCCSibLhnfKyR126MVnj5KOhtFSVe.#=zSKm_Mog=()
#=zCCSibLhnfKyR126MVnj5KOhtFSVe.#=zSpWwIfXjF_Bn(Boolean #=z7$j9AfM=)
#=z8bUdn7NB3HniUI$5rsmHmMh_8aU3.#=z_xK8kX8=(String #=zPA9blhSdh5oV, String #=zhNDd5pPctgqq, #=zjigdnpEe8jlppxNHW9WluVV6iGSI #=zyvQDV$M=, CryptoAlgorithm #=ztHPzHXvDFDl_, Boolean #=zwi6ylDV5lUBE)
Document.Encrypt(String userPassword, String ownerPassword, Permissions permissions, CryptoAlgorithm cryptoAlgorithm, Boolean usePdf20)
Document.Encrypt(String userPassword, String ownerPassword, DocumentPrivilege privileges, CryptoAlgorithm cryptoAlgorithm, Boolean usePdf20)
Sample.Encrypt() line 18

Any suggested workarounds?

I'm facing something related, and I'm fixed on an old version of Aspose, cannot upgrade for various reasons. My guess is something has changed in System.Security.Cryptography between .Net 8 & 9 - there's no way I know of to force only Aspose.PDF to use .Net 8 version of System.Security.Cryptography whilst the rest of the project stays on .Net 9, so I'm just going to have to downgrade the entire project

Curious @marc_s, is there a reason .NET 9.0 is preferable to Microsoft's own monikers net8.0 and net9.0 when writing questions?

This issue was resolved by upgrading to Aspose version 24.12.0.
@Hoodlum, I don't think this is what you're dealing with, but I chose to address the security vulnerability reference in Aspose v 24.12.0's reference to System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs 8.0 with a direct reference:
<PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs" Version="9.*" />

This override passed our test suite, including the use of password protection (which did not work under Aspose 21.12.0).
